# jQuery: $.getJSON edited data logs before edit happens

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to GET a json file from the server and edit the values before uploading it back.

When I try to log the data before editing, it shows the edited data instead.

What am I missing here?

```
    $.getJSON(url, 
        function(data,status,xhr){
            console.log("Original data"); 
            console.log(data);  //showing edited data instead of original data

            data["key"].FY = someValue;

            console.log("Edited data"); 
            console.log(data);
        });
```

I'm running this script on Firefox Version 67.0.2

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you use the Network inspector, what is the Param and Response data show?

Comment: @Twisty the response shows the original data

Comment: Ok, so this suggests the server is sending back the data correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It may be partially due to the Asynchronous nature of the function. Maybe try this:

```
var iData;
var nData = new Date().toString();
$.getJSON(url, function(data,status,xhr){ 
  console.log(data);
  iData = data;
  iData.key.FY = nData;
  console.log(data, iData);
});
```

Also best to use dot notation for Objects. It's also possible that maybe Cache is playing a part of things here. Make sure that your URL is not cached or or that data is not being cached.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I have tried your code and also cleared the cache, but all 3 logs still show the edited data.

I have also tried using the $.ajax method with async = false, but it doesn't work either.

Edit: I tried the $.ajax method with a text file and it's working as intented

Comment: @Ventil maybe your JSON has a syntax error? Maybe post an example of the data being returned.